# Telegram API, getChats returns null

Tags: telegram, telegram-api, tdlib

I'm wondering, why telegram api method `getChats` returns null?

I'm using python lib for the API call, but there is not anything special there

```
result = tg.call_method("getChats")
result.wait()
print(result.update)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python library that was used is called [python-telegram](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram/)

In this library when API faced an error - None (null) is returned.